# Which Android platform and API to target?

Tags: android, backwards-compatibility, platform

I'm just about to launch my first Android app, and it runs on the Android 1.1 platform, API Level 2, but is this what I should officially sign and launch the app as?  Does it affect performance at all or is it simply for Android to know which devices it works on?

The only problem I see is that I can't specify <supports-screens> in the Manifest, which I would like to do, but it appears I'd have to launch at 1.6 at least for this to work.

Would I be missing a huge number of phones by launching at 1.6 instead of 1.1?

Thank you!

Comment: You can't specify what in the Manifest?  I think you need to edit your question and format that part that says what you can't specify.

Comment: Thank you!!  It was supports-screens that was missing

Comment: There is a way to get supports-screen for 1.5. You build your application using 1.6 but you set the minSdk to 3 and targetSdk to 4. And you have to make sure you're not using any APIs from 1.6. If you don't do this your application won't be visible on Android Market from HTC Tattoo because it has a QVGA display. Read more about this here http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#strategies

Comment: Also consider targeting (and testing against) more recent versions, so the new versions don't need to turn on the compatibility modes described here:

http://developer.android.com/intl/de/reference/android/os/Build.VERSION_CODES.html

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Removing out of date info and info that I'm sure will be out of date in the near future.  Just go here to see what versions you should care about:

http://developer.android.com/resources/dashboard/platform-versions.html

Comment: Thank you, the chart helps a lot, I think 1.5 would be perfect, but it doesn't work with supports-screens.  I wonder if that will matter.

Comment: Dpends on what you are doing with supports-screens.  It's easy to test your app against different OS versions and screen resolutions using the emulator to see if there are any issues.

Comment: mbraid: Thank you! You did not just help him but also someone who is looking at the post after 2 years since it is posted

Answer (score 3):

I'd say 1.5 is a good choice for now. Have a look at the chart here: http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/12/knowing-is-half-battle.html

Answer (score 2):

Recent update of the Android fragmentation from [Android Tapp](http://www.androidtapp.com/finally-more-users-on-android-2-1-but-android-still-fragmented-chart/):

[Android fragmentation http://www.androidtapp.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/05/Finally-More-Users-on-Android-2.1-but-Android-Still-Fragmented-Chart.jpg](http://www.androidtapp.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/05/Finally-More-Users-on-Android-2.1-but-Android-Still-Fragmented-Chart.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

As far as I am concerned, I start developing targeting 1.5. When half finished, I would switch to 2.1 and when finished, I would try all versions in-between. I do not regard it necessary to mind any version lower 1.5 ... you cannot be downward compatible to the beginning of the universe ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Strategies for Legacy Applications
http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#strategies